# what is the use of MSRNE instruction in ARM

Tags: arm

Not able to find any documentation on this instruction

Is this a macro or an instruction. It is used mainly in context switch but not able to undetstand its purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an MSR instruction, conditionally executed as Not Equal (NE).

MSR is used to move a value from a general purpose register to a system co-processor register. This can be used for all manner of things, as the system co-processor allows. It is often used for things such as cache invalidation/flushing.

The NE part makes the instruction dependant on the Zero status flag being set to zero, this occurs as the result of a previous flag-setting operation.